# Maximum depth of binary tree- do we need a 'holder' to keep track of the maximum current depth?

Tags: python, tree

I a writing code to solve the following leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Here is the iterative solution that passes all the tests:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    stack = []

    if not root:
        return 0

    if root:
        stack.append((1,root))

    depth =0

    while stack:
        current_depth, root = stack.pop()

        depth = max(current_depth,depth)
        if root.left:
            stack.append((current_depth+1,root.left))
        if root.right:
            stack.append((current_depth+1,root.right))

    return depth
```

I do understand on the whole what is happening, but my question is with `depth = max(current_depth,depth)`. Am I right in understanding that the only purpose of `'depth'` is to act as a holder to hold the current maximum depth as we traverse the tree?

Because when reading the code initially, the first thing that struck me is why not ONLY have `current_depth`? But then it hit me that we need to store the current_depth somewhere and only keep the largest. Am I right on this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is with `depth = max(current_depth,depth)`. Am I right in understanding that the only purpose of `'depth'` is to act as a holder to hold the current maximum depth as we traverse the tree?

Yes, that is correct. Maybe it helps clarifying this point when you would replace this line with this equivalent code:

```
if current_depth > depth:
    depth = current_depth
```

> we need to store the `current_depth` somewhere and only keep the largest. Am I right on this point?

Yes, that is correct. During the execution of the algorithm, `current_depth` is fluctuating up and down, as you move up and down the stack. Actually, `current_depth` is always one less than the size of the stack after the `pop` (or equal to it before the `pop`) so if you really wanted to, you could do this without the `current_depth` variable, and rely only on `len(stack)`. In that case you don't even have to push that info on the stack. The outcome of the algorithm is really the maximum size that the stack reached during the whole execution:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    stack = []

    if not root:
        return 0

    if root:
        stack.append(root)

    depth =0

    while stack:
        depth = max(len(stack), depth)
        root = stack.pop()

        if root.left:
            stack.append(root.left)
        if root.right:
            stack.append(root.right)

    return depth
```

### Recursive versions

The original code you presented really is an almost literal conversion of a recursive function to an iterative function, introducing an explicit stack variable instead of the call stack frames you would produce in a recursive version.

It may also help to see the recursive implementation that this code mimics:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    if not root:
        return 0

    depth = 0

    def dfs(current_depth, root):  # <-- these variables live on THE stack
        nonlocal depth
        depth = max(current_depth, depth)
        if root.left:
            dfs(current_depth + 1, root.left)
        if root.right:
            dfs(current_depth + 1, root.right)

    dfs(1, root)
    return depth
```

And moving the three similar `if` statements one level deeper in the recursion tree, so to only have one `if`, we get:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    depth = 0

    def dfs(current_depth, root):
        nonlocal depth

        if root:
            depth = max(current_depth, depth)
            dfs(current_depth + 1, root.left)
            dfs(current_depth + 1, root.right)

    dfs(1, root)
    return depth
```

It is essentially the same algorithm, but it may help clarify what is happening.

We can turn this into a more functional version, which makes `dfs` *return* the `depth` value: that way you can avoid the `nonlocal` trick to mutate the `depth` value from inside that function:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    def dfs(current_depth, root):
        return max(current_depth, 
            dfs(current_depth + 1, root.left),
            dfs(current_depth + 1, root.right)
        ) if root else current_depth

    return dfs(0, root)
```

And now we can even merge that inner function with the outside function, by providing it an optional argument (`current_depth`) -- it should not be provided in the *main* call of `maxDepth`:

```
def maxDepth(root, current_depth=0):
    return max(current_depth, 
        maxDepth(root.left, current_depth + 1),
        maxDepth(root.right, current_depth + 1)
    ) if root else current_depth
```

And finally, the most elegant solution is to make `maxDepth` return the depth of the subtree that it is given, so without any context of the larger tree. In that case it is no longer necessary to pass a `current_depth` argument. The 1 is added *after* the recursive call is made, to account for the parent node:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    return 1 + max(
        maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)
    ) if root else 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information Trincot, everything makes so much more sense. Just one question, I noticed you included a 'nonlocal depth' in your latest code- is this necessary or just good coding practice? Because I have come across similar recursion situations where we keep the final_solution = [...] in the outer function and append to it within the recursion function, but in those they didn't use "nonlocal final_solution"

Comment: The `nonlocal` is necessary to allow the inner function to modify `depth`. It most closely resembles the iterative version, which also only has one `depth` variable. But it is not the most elegant solution, so I added some more variants. (also fixed a bug in the variants that were already in my answer).